# local apache httpd giving 403/I'm getting reverse proxy logging

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I'm running into a problem where I can't seem to run a development environment locally. I'm going into a project that already exists and is somewhat outdated; I'm more than happy to add any specifics that anyone needs.

I'm not sure exactly how to clarify my problem. Something is wrong with  the server -- the most notable is that in my error log I'm getting messages that I have a `reverse-proxy`, and I can't figure out why that's showing up.

The exact error messages:

```
[Wed Feb 26 13:11:56.161721 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53643] proxy_util.c(1908): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:rev
erse shared
[Wed Feb 26 13:11:56.162209 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53643] proxy_util.c(1965): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:rev
erse local
[Wed Feb 26 13:11:56.162300 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53643] proxy_util.c(2016): AH00931: initialized single connection
 worker in child 53643 for (*)
```

When I try to access the server running directly, I'm getting a `403 forbidden` error with message `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`.

Gah! I know this error report isn't really totally sufficient, but I'm not really sure what direction to go in here -- it's a situation where I don't know what I don't know, and I'm not 100% sure which of these avenues is worth exploring.

Some system information:

- OSx
- Running apache httpd locally
- several services map to this local server

Comment: Need to see your apache configuration and directives to understand the problem.

Comment: @EternalHour thank you for the help — got it resolved. The resolution involved symlinking the resource it was trying to access, but I feel like the solution is too specific to the domain I was working in to make it worth publishing